# Topology Manager scripts seem very slow

Tags: topology-manager, upgrade, sites-9.1

We're currently upgrading and SDL 9.1 environment, and we are creating the Topology Mappings for a series of Publications.

We have found that the commands `add-ttmmapping`, `add/set-ttmwebsite` etc. are very slow (and sometimes even resulting in timeouts).

After some debugging, it looks like the Discovery Service is the blocking factor.
Setting the debugging on shows that one `add-ttmmapping` command takes about 69 seconds to be processed by the Discovery Service.
It looks like the Discovery Service is looping through all Websites/WebApplications that are registered in the Topology, resulting in a fairly poor performance.

Is this expected behavior, or is there a configuration issue or a bug?

Comment: Do you have many websites/webapps and/or mappings for that CD Environment?

Comment: yes, there are indeed a large number of sites registered. When going through the debug log, it looks like the discovery service is looping through all of the created mappings/websites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some debugging, we finally found that the database server was provisioned in a different datacenter, causing some latency.
Since the discovery service is making a lot of database calls for one request (especially if you have a lot of publication mappings/websites), this latency (even very small latency) adds up and causes a long wait time.

Moving the database server to the correct datacenter caused requests to become normal again.